# C++ Convert Hex String Representation to Hex

Tags: c++, hex

I have searched here for an answer and either didn't find it or didn't understand it.

I need to convert a std::string such as "F1F2F3F4" (8 bytes) to bytes \xF1\xF2\xF3\xF4 (4 bytes).

I *think* I need `std::hex` but I'm confused by the examples I saw. After the conversion I need to access those bytes (as a char array) so that I can convert them to ASCII from EBCDIC (but that's another story).

So I think it would be something like this:

```
somevariable << std::hex << InputString;
```

But what should I use as somevariable? By the way, the InputString can be any length from 1 to 50-something or so.

My compiler is g++ 4.8 on Linux.

Comment: Please note that when you say "bytes xF1xF2xF3xF4 (4 bytes)" we might guess what you are trying to say, but this is not any widespread, or even slightly-spread notation.  An accepted notation, since you want an array, would be `[ 0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4 ]`.

Answer (score 4):

A simple (and slightly naive) way is to get two characters at a time from the input string, put in another string that you then pass to [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (or [`std::strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) if you don't have `std::stoi`) to convert to an integer that you can then put into a byte array.

For example something like this:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> bytes;  // The output "array" of bytes
std::string input = "f1f2f4f4";  // The input string

for (size_t i = 0; i < input.length(); i += 2)  // +2 because we get two characters at a time
{
    std::string byte_string(&input[i], 2);  // Construct temporary string for
                                            // the next two character from the input

    int byte_value = std::stoi(byte_string, nullptr, 16);  // Base 16
    bytes.push_back(byte_value);  // Add to the byte "array"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now my EBCDIC to ASCII function requires a char pointer. How do I convert the vector to a C string or I guess I could adapt the function to accept a vector...

Comment: (char *)bytes.data()  I guess

Comment: @RonC No, the vector is not null terminated. You could probably replace the `std::vector<uint8_t> bytes` with a `std::string` and do `bytes += (char) std::stoi(byte_string, nullptr, 16);` instead if you need a `data()` that is null terminated.

Comment: Now I'm struggling on the reverse--convert a std::string to a hex representation...

i.e., [ 0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4 ] to "F1F2F3F4"